# Viewing my Laravel site on local host on mac

Tags: laravel, xampp

I have had a search round here and can't find the answers I'm looking for and as I am a novice even the google searches that come up make it difficult to interpret.

My site is coded in Laravel, it was done for me by external developers.

I have downloaded my site from the git repository and have it on my local machine as I want to play around with it there and practice coding. This is proving difficult as the 'Laravel' thing seems to cause problems so I was just wondering if I could get some assistance.

I have XAMPP installed, I have composer installed, I have the site downloaded into my htdocs folder.

- Do I need to install Laravel seperately? Or would it have come through with the download from the repository?

**Regarding a seperate install if required.**
I have been using this site for instructions 
 - https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/install-laravel-5-on-os-x-23f3578386f1 
which suggests running this in terminal:
 - composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
Will this create a new Laravel project or just install it?

Thanks

Comment: `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist` will create a new laravel project

Comment: "composer update" would install dependencies your project need. 

Are you aware about xampp? like where to put code, database etc?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik I have put the whole site that I downloaded from the GIT repository in to the htdocs folder in XAMPP. Regarding the database that's actually one thing I have forgotten to do. I must add this.

Comment: Then also "composer update" would necessary to update dependencies with latest version.

Answer (score 3):

So we will assume your project name which you have downloaded is `my_project`.  we will use the terminal:

```
// to enter the project root directory
- cd my_project  

// to install all the dependencies
- composer install 

// to generate the app key
- php artisan key:generate 

// to update, create tables in DB as well as seed data.
- php artisan migrate --seed

// to start the development server
- php artisan serve
```

**Then** in your browser go to http://localhost:8000